# What is the best practice to update <version/> in package.xml?

Tags: bestpractice, mavensmate, version-control

For example,
The current `<version/>` should be 40.0 (Summer '17).
However, the latest MavensMate (v0.0.11-beta.7) uses 34.0.

1. What are some best practices for updating `<version/>` in `package.xml` in a code repository (such as BitBucket) when the whole team uses MavensMate for coding?
2. How frequently is it recommended to update `<version/>`?
   Is it recommended to update it with every release (thrice a year)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To my knowledge, there is only the manual way to update package.xml for mavensmate - if setting the api version in mavensmate settings does not work to your expectations. Personally, I use [CumulusCI](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCI/) for most package.xml related tasks. CCI lets me choose for which API version to build the package XML on project level.
2. As best practice, I recommend avoiding updating to a new API Version without due cause. That means: If you don't need to update, don't.

Comment: (1) If you manually update `<version/>34.0<version/>` to `<version/>40.0<version/>`, Mavensmate remembers the older package.xml file. E.g., try to manually add a new class in the package which wasn't there before, and it won't be fetched by Mavensmate. It starts working again when you revert version back to 34.0.

(2) I agree and upvote your idea to AVOID updating to new `<version/>` without due cause, even though it sounds bad.

Comment: Have you set the api version in Mavensmate settings?

Comment: Nope not working. I tried replacing both: API version in Mavensmate settings to 40.0 and package.xml to 40.0. I deleted all files locally (except package.xml) and refreshed from server - and package.xml automatically reverted to 34.0. I repeated the experiment with 39.0 and package.xml was again reverted to 34.0.

Comment: Sorry to hear, then Im out of ideas. For what it's worth, I've ditched Atom+MM in favour of VS Code + ForceCode

Comment: API version in Mavensmate settings works in stable Mavensmate, but doesn't work in Mavensmate beta.

Comment: Are u still actively using MM albeit discontinued? I have moved completely to VS Code and command line (cci, sfdx)

Answer (score 1):

There are two places where the API version matters.

- src/package.xml
- MavensMate Global Settings

You already know about src/package.xml, but you should also know that when MavensMate deploys or retrieves a package, it's actually invoking the API version defined in Global Settings. See screenshot below.

[image: MavensMate Global Settings Salesforce API Version]

Once you make both changes you're good to go. One consideration if you're using a version control system like Git: When upgrading the package, you'll want to create a pull request that takes your package as-is and upgrades it to the new version. This will keep your commit history clean and clearly show the upgrade in-place with no modifications to functionality.

Comment: If you delete all folders from SRC locally (only keeping package.xml), and then right-click SRC and refresh from server, does package.xml stay on 39.0 or revert to 34.0? Mine reverts to 34.0 despite following the two bullet points you mentioned.

Comment: Check your Global Settings, @ShumonSaha. And the API version looks right there, then re-authenticate with MavensMate to start a new session on the right API version.